# Why does not app update appear in Software Center?

Tags: software-center, application-development

I have submitted an update (v 1.1.0) for [Brightness Controller](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/) and it was packaged about two months ago.

But it still does not appear in Software Centre. It shows 1.0.1 (the previous version)
[image]

However, it show v 1.1.0 in the Online catalog. I see there are some reviews for 1.1.0, so some people got the update.

How to get the latest version? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
[image]

Comment: uninstall brightness controller , and then retry :-)

Comment: and remove ppa for brighness controller(if any )

Comment: @Tachyons I have fixed the problem. After removing the PPA, software center showed 1.1 but installed 1.0.1. I found that the PPA had raring as distribution. I changed it to trusty and it worked. Actually, 1.0.1 was the last submitted version when raring was supported. However, it was my new installation (not upgraded) and I have no idea why such a thing happened. I am going to post the solution. Some other users may also be affected, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened USC and can see the later version of your app there.

[image]

Comment: But I cannot. I have tried using update manager and updating apt-get. Is there any fix?

Comment: Try removing your current installed version, updating your sources & then see what shows up.

Comment: I have removed it and did `sudo apt-get update` but no avail.

Comment: I even purged software center and reinstalled but no use.

Comment: What does "apt-cache policy brightness-controller" report?

Comment: @popey I have fixed the problem. After removing the PPA, software center showed 1.1 but installed 1.0.1. I found that the PPA had raring as distribution. I changed it to trusty and it worked. Actually, 1.0.1 was the last submitted version when raring was supported. However, it was my new installation (not upgraded) and I have no idea why such a thing happened. I am going to post the solution. Some other users may also be affected, right?